# FFMPEG Concatenate multiple videos causes: Too many invisible frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

i'm trying to concatenate multiple `.webm` files in a single one. One of these files is a simple black video generated with the next command:

```sh
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:d=5.2 black.webm
```

Then this is `concat_list.txt`

```
file 'black.webm'
file '1.webm'
file '2.webm'
file '3.webm'
```

Finally i try to concatenate files with:

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat_list.txt -c copy video.webm
```

The result is a long list of this message:

```
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fcecef00180] Too many invisible frames
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fcecef00180] Failed to receive packet from filter vp9_superframe for stream 0
```

[Complete log](https://pastebin.com/mZDt1eBp)

The problem seems to be the `black.webm` file. I removed it from the `concat_list.txt` and **everything works fine**.

It's important to mention that none of these files has an audio stream.

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i black.webm -i 1.webm`

Comment: @llogan [here](https://pastebin.com/mZDt1eBp) is the complete log with `-loglevel debug`

Comment: Unfortunately that is the log for `ffmpeg -f concat -i concat_list.txt -c copy video.webm -loglevel debug` which is not what I need. I am looking for information about each input listed in `concat_list.txt`. Please provide the complete output from the command I provided (without `-loglevel dedug`).

Comment: My bad, [here](https://pastebin.com/BRLF9qAG) it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All inputs to be concatenated must have the same attributes. `black.webm` is different than `1.webm`. It has a different format, width, and height.

Try:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x360:d=5.2 -c:v libvpx black.webm
```

Comment: It is working, but i checked the output of `ffmpeg -i 1.webm -i 2.webm` [(otuput)](https://pastebin.com/mJ9t04hD) and both has different width and height, however there is no problem when i concatenate just those files. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Silmood I was assuming `2.webm` and `3.webm` were going to be the same as `1.webm` but I was mistaken. It appears you have various and arbitrary input attribute differences. Is this concatenation a one time task, or will you be concatenating many times using arbitrary inputs? If you are doing this often I recommend using the concat filter instead so you can conform all inputs to a common set of attributes and do it all in one command. If you are only concatenating these 4 files then you can re-encode the other files to match the attributes of the longest input then concat.